# How to Create a Tkinter Widget Similar to Stack Overflow Tags with DropDown menu and Removal Feature?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frontend, tags

I'm working on a Python project and I want to implement a Tkinter widget that functions similarly to how tags work on Stack Overflow. Specifically, I'd like to have an entry field where users can type in keywords, and as they type, a dropdown menu appears with autocomplete suggestions based on previously entered keywords. When a keyword is selected from the dropdown and the user presses enter, it should become a single word with an 'x' button on the right side that allows the user to remove it.

I have seen similar functionality on websites like Stack Overflow, and I think it would be a useful feature for my application. However, I'm relatively new to Tkinter and I'm not sure how to implement this. Can someone provide guidance or a code example on how to create such a widget using Python and Tkinter?

Any help, suggestions, or pointers to relevant documentation or libraries would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Imgs for reference:
[image: img3]

[image: img3]

Comment: I don't think `tkinter` has that built-in. But you can always make it yourself using frames+labels.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to tkinter, but you can pretty easily accomplish this with an `Entry` widget and a `Toplevel` or `Frame` with some labels or text widgets.

Comment: oh k I actually did it haha

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.